# Firebase Silence Push Notification with HTTP V1

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send `content_available: true` for silent notifications. But it doesnt work with HTTPS v1. And there's no explanation in documentation.

It was like that on previous api: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref but couldnt find any documentation for http v1.

What is the correct payload for sending silent notifications any ideas?

```js
{
  "message": {
    "content_available": true,
    "topic": "device",
    "data": {
      "order_id": 123123,
      "notification_type": 1,
      "app_name": "my app"
    },
    "notification": {
      "title": "Your Edit Request",
      "body": "Edit was requested from my app"
    },
    "android": {
      "notification": {
        "sound": "default"
      }
    },
    "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "sound": "default"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since content_available is specific to iOS, you should add it under the [`apns`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig) property.